In what cases can $k_{\rm cat}/K_{\rm M}$ be used to compare catalytic efficiency？
The ratio $k_{\rm cat}/K_{\rm M}$ is often used to compare the catalytic efficiency of enzymes, but this  paper has suggested that $k_{\rm cat}/K_{\rm M}$ should be abandoned for enzyme comparison. This confuses me. Should this ratio not be used in any cases, or can it still be used under some conditions, such as under low substrate concentration, $[\ce{S}]\ll K_{\rm M}$? If $k_{\rm cat}/K_{\rm M}$ is abandoned, how can we comprehensively analyze and compare the efficiency of enzymes? $k_{\rm cat}$ alone seems to only be applicable when $[\ce{S}]\gg K_{\rm M}$.

This appears to be an improved formulation of a previous question, in which case you should delete the original.
